# Python sqlite server uses 100% CPU

Tags: python, sockets, sqlite

My code is below.

This is the server that listens to the clients requests to database in sqlite3. When I run it with system (debian, rc.local or crontab) it uses 100% of CPU and work really slow. When I run it from terminal, what is extremely uncomfortable, everything works fine for about an hour, and then the CPU usage grows to 100% too. I guess there is a problem with loops, but I don't see the solution.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python
import select 
import io
import socket 
import sys 
import threading 
import pickle
import struct
import os
import binascii
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import sqlite3 
import datetime
import unicodedata
from shutil import copyfile
class Server: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.host = self.get_ip_address()
        self.port = 50000 
        self.backlog = 5 
        self.size = 1024 
        self.server = None 
        self.threads = [] 

    def get_ip_address(self):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
        return s.getsockname()[0]  
    def open_socket(self): 
        try: 
            self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
            self.server.bind((self.host,self.port)) 
            self.server.listen(5) 
        except socket.error, (value,message): 
            if self.server: 
                self.server.close() 
            print "Could not open socket: " + message 
            sys.exit(1) 

    def run(self): 
        self.open_socket() 
        input = [self.server,sys.stdin] 
        running = 1 
        while running: 
            inputready,outputready,exceptready = select.select(input,[],[]) 

            for s in inputready: 

                if s == self.server: 
                    # handle the server socket 
                    c = Client(self.server.accept()) 
                    c.start() 
                    self.threads.append(c) 

                #elif s == sys.stdin: 
                    # handle standard input 
                    #junk = sys.stdin.readline() 
                    #running = 0 

        # close all threads 

        self.server.close() 
        for c in self.threads: 
            c.join() 

class Client(threading.Thread): 
    def __init__(self,(client,address)): 
        threading.Thread.__init__(self) 
        self.client = client 
        self.address = address 
        self.size = 1024 

    def run(self): 
        running = 1 
        while running: 
            sock = self.client
            data = self.recv_msg(sock)
            if data is not None:
                data = pickle.loads(data)
                userid=data[0]
                zap = data[1]
                zap2 = data[2]
                if zap == '1':
                    conn = sqlite3.connect('base.db')
                    zap2 = str(zap2)
                    odp = conn.execute(zap2)
                    data = odp.fetchall()
                    liczba = len(data)
                elif zap == '999':
                    conn = sqlite3.connect('base.db')
                    userid = str(data[0])
                    hour_now = str(datetime.date.today())
                    date_today = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())[:5]
                    conn.execute("update people set hour_end='"+hour_now+"' where userid='"+userid+"' and date='"+date_today+"'")
                    conn.commit()
                data = pickle.dumps(data)
                msg = struct.pack('>I', len(data)) + data
                self.client.sendall(msg)
            else: 
                self.client.close() 
                running = 0 

    def recv_msg(self, sock):
        # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
        raw_msglen = self.recvall(sock, 4)
        if not raw_msglen:
            return None
        msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
        # Read the message data
        return self.recvall(sock, msglen)

    def recvall(self, sock, n):
        # Helper function to recv n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
        data = ''
        while len(data) < n:
            packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
            if not packet:
                return None
            data += packet
        return data 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    s = Server() 
    s.run()
```

Comment: `packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))` aren't you supposed to call this function with 2 arguments `(sock, n)`?

Comment: @N.Ivanov socket.recv(bufsize[, flags]) in documentation there is only one argument. Function recvall needs two arguments and it has: self.recvall(sock, 4)

Comment: my bad, I have misread it. sorry

Comment: I think there should be:
while running:
    ...
    if not data:
        break
it works very well and doesn't have those issues in the code from the link: http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-server-code-example/ 
So, my problem is solved

Comment: then write it as a detailed answer and accept it, so that future visitors can find a solution easier. Thanks!